# JavaFx Calendar Picker Api JFXTras

Tags: javafx-8

Here I created the calendar picker by using JFXtras API and here I am getting events from Spring rest web service and highlighting the calendar dates by using highlight observable list.

But here my requirement is what ever the highlighted date if we click then we have to show the events on that date,to do that i wants to get the date from calendar picker,but what listener i want to use to get the selected date.

```
    CalendarPicker calendarPicker = interfaceHandler.getCalendarPicker();
    calendarPicker.setMode(Mode.MULTIPLE);

    ObservableList<Calendar> calendars = calendarPicker
            .highlightedCalendars();

    if (listOfEvents != null && listOfEvents.size() > 0) {
        for (Events events : listOfEvents) {

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "MM/dd/yyyy");

            Date date = events.getEventDate();
            System.out.println("+"
                    + simpleDateFormat.format(events.getEventDate()));

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(date);
            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            System.out.println("+=year" + year);

            Calendar gc = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);

            simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(gc);
            calendars.add(gc);
            System.out.println("The Size=" + calendars.size());

            // DatePicker
        }

    }
    //calendarPicker
    // calendarPicker.setCalendarRangeCallback(value,calendar);
    System.out.println("+=" + calendars);

    System.out.println(calendarPicker.displayedCalendar());
    CalendarPickerControlSkin calendarPickerControlSkin = new CalendarPickerControlSkin(
            calendarPicker);
    calendarPickerControlSkin.setShowWeeknumbers(ShowWeeknumbers.NO);
    calendarPicker.setSkin(calendarPickerControlSkin);
```

Comment: Please add some code and/or a documentation of what you've already tried and what exactly your problem is.

Comment: Hi Mob i uploaded the code please can u help on this issue,it is very appreciated.

Comment: Got it i added mouse event listener to capture the selection event.